# Succesful boot with displayed “trace” - why? Impending crash?

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair

Ubuntu 20.04 with dual boot: ubuntu on sda lvm full disk encryption and windows on sdb no encryption.

I'm always see the attached trace command displaying on screen - wondering how much longer before the system crashes.

After succesfull entering of credentials, more rapdily scrolling commands all in green with only one in red flashing by so quickly I can't capture it.

Any help much aprpeciatred on what this trace message means and does it fortel impending failure as well as how to capture the RED error message.

[image]

Comment: To me, this looks like the normal terminal output of Ubuntu booting, when the splash screen has been turned off.  You can open a terminal window and use `journalctl -b` to examine the journal for the current boot, and `journalctl -b -p 3`  to show warning level 'error' and higher/